# Drag&Drop on (windows) desktop touchcreen

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, touch

I'm using Bernardo Castilhos' HTML 5 Drag&Drop Polyfill:

https://github.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch

Here is a demo:

http://bernardo-castilho.github.io/DragDropTouch/demo/index.htm

Some time ago it stopped working on windows-based desktop touchscreens. I do not test it very often on those devices so I don't know when it stopped working.

In firefox browser a preceding double tap on the element makes the dragging working, in chrome / edge all the actions on the touchscreen are ignored.

Does anybody has a workaround for enabling "HTML5 draggable=true" elements on windows touchscreens? It works perfectly on android / iOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed:  https://github.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch/issues/40

But the developer forgot to update his own demo / example-page.

So just use the version from april that is provided at github and it works.